# application_controller.rb not being loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app (running on rails 2.3.5, ruby 1.8.7), my application_controller.rb file is not being loaded automatically when `config.cache_classes = false` in environment.rb.

It's in the load path. If I add `require 'application_controller'` to the end of my environment.rb or set `cache_classes = true`, then the app works fine.

Why wouldn't it load when classes are not being cacehed?

Comment: The application code is loaded as part of the `Rails::Initializer.run` method in environment.rb. It's almost the last step. I know of nothing that would prevent the application controller from loading -- my only suggestion is to make sure there is not a typo in the filename `/app/controllers/application_controller.rb` and to make sure there is not a typo in the class definition `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`.

Comment: Is your application created using rails 2.3.5 or just moved to this version?

Comment: I'd like to add that the first part my last comment applies to production mode, where the classes are eager-loaded in `Rails::Initializer#load_application_classes`, but in development mode it does not cache classes, so loads them as part of a const missing catcher each request.

Comment: Thanks @Ben... but post as an answer so I can upvote you :-)

Comment: @Naren: I'm not sure (I just started work on this particular app) but I'll check.

Comment: @Craig, ok, I added it as an answer. Was a typo the problem?

Comment: @Ben, you're on to something: if I run `script/server --environment=test` then application_controller.rb is loaded. It looks like a problem with the dev environment only.

Comment: @Craig: If application is not created using rails 2.3.5 then rename application_controller.rb to application.rb. and try running your app.

Comment: Thanks @Naren, but that didn't help. :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it for some reason your app is still using 2.3.2 gems for `ActiveSupport`. It is probably still looking for `application.rb`, and the undefined `pretty_inspect` also lends itself to a versioning problem.

First, make sure that you don't have something like this at the top of your `environment.rb`:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.2'
```

If you don't, then at the bottom of the your `environment.rb` find out if something else is setting it wrong by adding this:

```
puts RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Comment: This was one of the things I thought of too... but no, it's 2.3.5 anywhere I can find it. Checked my ruby version too (1.8.7).

Comment: I *am* using rvm and a clean ruby/rails/gems install, so that was a big concern. But everything I can see points to it being a clean & proper install.

Comment: Hmm... I'm fresh out of ideas then. Are you sure your vendored gems are right (or that your system gems are right if not vendoring)? In any case, if I were you I would definitely look into why `pretty_inspect` was undefined there. I bet it's related to the main problem you are having.

Comment: Double check your gems list in both your system ruby and your rvm ruby. Just make sure the rails-relevant ones are in sync in both. There shouldn't be any cross-pollination between the ruby installations, but I would sync them just in case there is (and if the sync does solve the problems, then you've got a more focused place to look for why the crossover is happening).

Comment: oh, and if your gems aren't frozen, i'd definitely recommend freezing them `rake rails:freeze:gems VERSION=2.3.5`

Comment: Now here is something *really* weird... it's started working all of a sudden, without any changes on my part. ????

Comment: Hah. That was my 4th idea -- co-worked temporarily changed your code just to mess with you...

Comment: As it turned out, this was (nearly) the correct answer. The codebase had a bunch of monkey patches to ApplicationController that apparently were being loaded in a different order on my system. One of the other devs then reorganized the changes; when I pulled the code (which I guess I forgot I did), it fixed the issue and then started working again.

Answer (score 1):

The application code is loaded as part of the `Rails::Initializer.run` method in environment.rb. It's almost the last step. I know of nothing that would prevent the application controller from loading -- my only suggestion is to make sure there is not a typo in the filename `/app/controllers/application_controller.rb` and to make sure there is not a typo in the class definition `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`.

I'd like to add that the first part my last comment applies to production mode, where the classes are eager-loaded in `Rails::Initializer#load_application_classes`, but in development mode it does not cache classes, so loads them as part of a const_missing catcher each request. See [ActiveSupport::Dependencies#load_missing_constant](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/load_missing_constant).

Answer (score 1):

I have another idea. You mentioned that it is in the load path, but I would confirm later on that it stays in the load path and that a plugin doesn't mess it up or something. At the very bottom of `environment.rb` (last line) add this line:

`puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths.pretty_inspect`

Then run a `script/server` from the command line and take a look at the load paths, making sure `/path_to_your_rails_app/app/controllers` shows up.

Comment: I get `undefined method `pretty_inspect' for #<Array:0x1016b4ae8>`, which seems weird to me. However, `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths` does indeed list `/Users/craig/Sites/<projectname>/app/controllers/` as the first line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely related to `config.cache_classes = false`; if I switch this to `true` then the problem disappears.

(Thanks @Ben Lee for leading me towards this)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but check out `ActiveSupport::Dependencies#load_missing_constant` at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/load_missing_constant -- this is the important part of the rails const_missing magic. Take a look at the source code and see if it gives you any ideas.